# Can the changes made in the parent table reflect in the view in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I make a insert/delete an entry the base/parent table of a view, will the view reflect those changes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zsuzsa, will it reflect the changes made on multi parent tables as well?

Comment: Yes, changes would reflect in  view, if you change the any value in tables on which view is created. but it may cause errors if you alter the table with change in column name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the changes are reflected in all cases, even when the view has multiple parent tables.